# Performance problem Fedora 23 32-bit @ Dell D630 4GB/Nvidia

Tags: linux, gnome, performance, profiling

I have installed *Fedora 23 32-bit* at *Dell D630 4GB* with *NVidia Quattro NVS 135M* (nvidia.ko, not nouveau.ko). 
And I have permanent performance problem as X-Windows (Gnome) are very slow and laggy. I can see that loads of Xorg, gnome-shell, firefox, thunderbird are high. Even I don't do anything special (like video or so) I can see particular program loads 100% (2 Core CPU) (e.g 80% Xorg, 70% firefox). AFAIR I saw a note that Nvidia apparently dislikes PAE. I can see in perf that *native_sched_clock* takes majority of CPU in many applications. Is it normal (maybe it's app idle)?
Why Xorg has so high load and gnome-shell as well ?

Has anybody idea what might be wrong and what to focus on to get it running normal speed ? What about a HW problem, should it lead to this state ?

```
uname -a
Linux hypo 4.4.6-301.fc23.i686+PAE #1 SMP Wed Mar 30 17:57:13 UTC 2016 i686 i686 i386 GNU/Linux

# almost idle, just Alt-Tab to another app
top
asks: 211 total,   2 running, 209 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
%Cpu(s): 18,0 us,  7,6 sy,  0,0 ni, 74,1 id,  0,2 wa,  0,0 hi,  0,2 si,  0,0 st
KiB Mem :  4133244 total,   245772 free,  2542016 used,  1345456 buff/cache
KiB Swap:  5631996 total,  4825204 free,   806792 used.  1424184 avail Mem 

  PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND                                                                           
11447 root      20   0  268892 163992  43132 S  24,5  4,0 211:12.13 Xorg                                                                              
11565 tma       20   0  810168 310220  48032 S  12,9  7,5  71:52.12 gnome-shell                                                                       
12052 tma       20   0  873620 249792  55232 S   6,6  6,0  89:36.52 thunderbird                                                                       
25148 tma       20   0 1147616 428300  94740 S   2,6 10,4   3:51.10 firefox                                                                           
13194 tma       20   0  125632  55148  15320 S   0,7  1,3   3:44.70 gnome-terminal-                                                                   
26716 tma       20   0  527872 156424  78716 S   0,7  3,8   0:40.99 chromium-browse                                                                   

perf record -a
Samples: 578K of event 'cycles:p', Event count (approx.): 57813200, DSO: [kernel.kallsyms]
Overhead  Command          Symbol                                                                                             ◆
  30,84%  Xorg             [k] native_sched_clock                                                                             ▒
  18,40%  gnome-shell      [k] native_sched_clock                                                                             ▒
  11,81%  swapper          [k] native_sched_clock                                                                             ▒
  11,40%  chromium-browse  [k] native_sched_clock                                                                             ▒
   9,82%  firefox          [k] native_sched_clock                                                                             ▒
   1,71%  Xorg             [k] nmi                                                                                            ▒
   1,60%  gnome-terminal-  [k] native_sched_clock                                                                             ▒
   1,21%  java             [k] native_sched_clock                                                                             ▒
   1,02%  gnome-shell      [k] nmi                                                                                            ▒
   0,87%  Chrome_IOThread  [k] native_sched_clock                                                                             ▒
   0,83%  perf             [k] native_sched_clock                                                                             ▒
   0,76%  Chrome_ChildIOT  [k] native_sched_clock                                                                             ▒
   0,75%  systemd-journal  [k] native_sched_clock                                                                             ▒
   0,66%  swapper          [k] nmi                                                                                     


# some modules
lsmod
nvidia               9535488  64
wmi                    20480  1 dell_wmi
video                  32768  2 dell_wmi,dell_laptop
wl                   6209536  0
dell_laptop            24576  0
....
```